# Project Server 2016 PSI with ADFS

Tags: adfs, project-server, psi

a customer of ours recently uses ADFS on their Project Server 2016 environment. We have some solutions deployed that communicate with PSI. After using ADFS, the PSI however cannot be reached. We receive following error:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.
```

In ULS, I found following entries:

```
Claims Authentication   0   Unexpected  User-Agent is empty
...
Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth request.     IsAuthenticated=False, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0
...
Claims Authentication   af30r   Medium  Multiauth SPWebApplication with widnows enabled and MS-OFBA accepted was set to false for the request url 'https://***/PPM/_vti_bin/PSI/ProjectServer.svc'.
General b6p2    Medium  Sending HTTP response 401 - text/plain:401 UNAUTHORIZED.
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Is there a sample available on how to deal with ADFS and PSI?

Comment: not solved yet?